# Adding conditions in where clause based on another condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement like this

```
SELECT t.Date, t.Time, t.Location, t.Name 
FROM abc AS t
INNER JOIN
INNER JOIN
....
....
WHERE 
    CAST(t.Date AS date) = some date
    AND t.Location = some location
```

My requirement is this: in the `WHERE` clause, I need to add another condition for `t.Time = some condition` - but only if `t.Name LIKE '%pink%'`.

If `t.Name` doesn't contain "pink", I don't need to have `t.Time` in the `WHERE` clause.

I tried using a case statement and using different combinations of AND, OR but its not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `where t.date = 'some date' and (t.location = 'some location' or (t.location = 'some other location' and t.name like '%pink%' ))`

Comment: t.location should always be there. I need to be able to add t.Time only if t.Name has pink in it. if t.name doesnt have pink in it, i dont need to have t.Time in the where clause.

Comment: You have to have some sort of `OR` here - something like `t.date = <date> and location = <loc> and ((t.time = <time> AND t.name like '%pink%') OR t.time > <the beginning of time>`).

Comment: Please read and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The logical condition `A implies B` is equivalent to `(not A) or B`. Therefore, your additional condition `(t.name like '%pink%') implies (t.Time = some condition)` would become `AND (t.Name NOT LIKE '%pink%' OR t.Time = some condition)`.

Comment: SIDE NOTE: If you are storing dates and times as text fields, then you should consider redesigning your database to use proper date, time or datetime data types. In the query posted above, the condition `CAST(t.Date AS date) = some date` will prevent SQL Server query optimizer from using an index to directly locate the desired records. As your database grows, the performance will suffer.  If you really need easy access to dates and times as text, consider defining a view or adding computed columns.